# Alert box in PHP - Making me crazy

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I know this question is very common, I have search alot, and after alot of hard work, I am asking here.

I simply want to show an alert box and redirect it to a page.

The code below is redirecting me, but not showing me the alert box.

Please, let me know my mistake.

```
<?php

require_once('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['person'])){ $name = $_POST['person']; } 
if(isset($_POST['pwd'])){ $password = $_POST['pwd']; } 
if(isset($_POST['position'])){ $pos = $_POST['position']; }  

if(empty($name) or empty($password))
{ 

echo "<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>
alert('Places should not be empty! Press Ok and try again!');
window.location.replace(\"addmember.php\");
</SCRIPT>"; 
}

else
{
//$query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into members (username, password,position) values ('$name','$password','$pos')");

echo "<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>
alert('Added!');
window.location.replace(\"addmember.php\");
</SCRIPT>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a JavaScript redirect when the condition comes from PHP.

Comment: what's in `$message`? YOu're are major risk of introducing JS syntax errors by dumping php text directly into a javascript context.

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @MarcB $message is a variable. Which will contain the message.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text!**

Comment: @JayBlanchard; I found this script code on internet; its was working yesterday with my login page.

Comment: @SLaks: What is XSS vulnerability?

Comment: You need to learn far more about security before you can create a secure authentication system.  You should use an existing, proven, system.

Comment: Here's a resource that has information about SQL injections and XSS injections, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A1-Injection. A bit old but should give you a starting point.

Comment: @SLaks Wel, I am really new in all this stuff. Learning these things in my summer.

Comment: @SLaks He is not having an XSS vulnerability , but its propense to SQL Injection with that exact code (using user input directly to query database)

Comment: @SLaks Can you please guide me how to correct this?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Can you please guide me, how show an alert and than direct a page?

Comment: @user134179 are you having an exact error? tried the alert and redirection and it worked..

 $message = 'shikaka';
       echo "<script>
            alert('$message');
            window.location.replace(\"addmember.php\");
            </script>";
        
        die();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally make this function to show an alert box and redirect it to a page.

```
function do_alert($msg,$link=NULL) 
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">             
    alert("' . $msg . '"); 
    </script>';

    if(!empty($link)) {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">             
        window.location="'.$link.'";
    </script>';
    }
}
```

Use this function both alert and redirect to a page use this

```
do_alert("Message","URL"); 
do_alert("Here this is your alert","addmember.php");
do_alert("Only your alert");
```

If the function 2nd parameter URL is empty then it'll only do alert.

Comment: What does the if statement inside do_alert do?

Comment: check if 2nd parameter is exist or not. if you put url (as 2nd parameter )to redirect the page after alert.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
window.location.replace(\"addmember.php\");
```

to

```
window.location='addmember.php';
```